# What is the difference between Layout and Template in Nextjs 13?

Tags: reactjs, templates, layout, next.js

Could someone explain to me the difference between them?

I feel like a layout and template are the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're asking about templates and layouts in NextJS 13?

Templates and layouts can both wrap child layouts or pages.

Layouts persist across routes and maintain their state. Templates create a new instance for each of their children on navigation, no state is preserved and DOM elements are re-created.

Use templates for:

- transitional animations
- logic that relies on useEffect or useState like tracking analytics or form submissions.

Vercel recommends using layouts over templates unless necessary, but you can use both in the same route segment.

Comment: One important difference is that layouts components get access the the query params using their `props.params`, unlike templates which get nothing in their props